# Where in wordpress backend exists Layout CSS/JS > Javascript

Tags: wordpress

I try to find under this path `Tools > Layout CSS/JS > Javascript` aiming to reproduce [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-keep-accordions-open-2/) but I can find this. Is there any plugin I should use?

Comment: It's a setting for the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/beaver-builder-lite-version/ You need to check your wordpress Dashboard for the Beaver builder settings and go to Tools > Layout CSS/JS > Javascript

Comment: Do you have the Beaver Builder Plugin installed?